# Pgadmin4: Error module 'paramiko' has no attribute 'Ed25519Key'

Tags: ubuntu, paramiko, pgadmin, ssh-tunnel

This only happens when you attempt to connect to a database with pgadmin using ssh tunneling. The most up-to-date version of paramiko and pgadmin4 in the ubuntu 18.04 repositories will not fix the issue.

Comment: Your paramiko is apparently older than 2.1, upgrading might help, but I ended up removing the references from sshtunnel.py because >2.2 versions of paramiko had other bugs

Answer (score 18):

This issue is caused because the sshtunnel python3 library attempts to load `paramiko.Ed25519Key` regardless of whether the version of paramiko installed supports this keytype or not. The easiest workaround I found was to install a newer version of python3-paramiko using the latest proposed deb from launchpad:

```
sudo apt install python3-bcrypt
wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/python3-paramiko_2.4.1-0ubuntu2_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i python3-paramiko_2.4.1-0ubuntu2_all.deb
```

Then restart pgadmin, and connecting to a database via an ssh tunnel should work again.

Comment: This gave me the tip I needed to get started... sadly, on Xenial, this requires a ton of other packages to be installed.... had to follow the rabbit trail of installations, and I finally got pgadmin up and working. Thanks!

Comment: If you install `gdebi` and you use it instead of `dpkg -i` should install de dependencies automatically @DavidMorton

Comment: this was the right solution for me versions change. so additional info for future visitors. 
- available paraminko version for bionic (18.04): 2.0.0 (published: 2018-10-29) causing trouble. 
- available paraminko version for disco (18.10): 2.4.2 (published: 2019-01-19) resolves. 
All versions:
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/paramiko

Answer (score 1):

This is a rather janky solution, but removing the `Ed25519Key` referencing options and code in `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sshtunnel.py` will also work (so long as you don't need that option at least).

Comment: I did what you suggested and it was easy to make the Ed25519Key to go away. However, after that I got errors 'Could not establish session to SSH gateway' and ''Could not connect to gateway". I solved it by establishing an SSH Tunnel outside of pgadmin and then using that from pgadmin.